# Loading Google Web Fonts using require.js font plugin

Tags: javascript, fonts, requirejs, google-webfonts

I'm using `https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins` to load the google font and it works fine for the basic font.

```
require.config({
  paths : {
    font: 'lib/require/font',
  }
});

define([
  'font!google,families:[Roboto]'
  ], function(){
    //all dependencies are loaded
  }
);
```

the above is fine, but if I try `Roboto:400,500,700,900`, it won't work to load the bolder fonts.

Comment: Hey @Joe did you end up getting a solution to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
define(['backbone','app-init','font!google,families:[Yanone Kaffeesatz:700]'],
   function(Backbone, AppInit,Font) {
      AppInit.initialize();
   }
);
```

Comment: I get Uncaught ReferenceError: WebFont is not defined

Comment: What other requirements are needed to get this working