# How do you set up requirejs and Google Web Fonts?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, google-font-api, google-webfonts

I am using [requirejs-plugins](https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins) and am trying to load some google web fonts into my script to use.I have found several examples more or less mimicking those of the example on that github page.

Example: [Loading Google Web Fonts using require.js font plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19234299/loading-google-web-fonts-using-require-js-font-plugin)

I have also read the source of the font plugin and tried this in my example and it still does not work.

```
Line 28:
example: font!google,families:[Tangerine,Cantarell,Yanone Kaffeesatz:700]
```

This is my code so far.

```
requirejs.config({
    font: '../bower_components/requirejs-plugins/src/font',
    propertyParser: '../bower_components/requirejs-plugins/src/propertyParser'
});

define(['font!google,families:[Yanone Kaffeesatz:700]'], function(Font) {
    console.log(Font);
});
```

This is the error fired in console on load.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: WebFont is not defined
```

This happens on line 38 of font.js

What is happening here? I feel like I am missing some kind of configuration or something. As you can see I am using the exact example import as the script suggests . Are there any examples out there of this actually being used?

Answer (score 4):

After some investigation, I found that there is actually a bug already listed at https://github.com/millermedeiros/requirejs-plugins/issues/71 as a result of a code change that was made. The bug was listed 16 days ago and is still open which doesn't help you. In the meantime you should be able to make the following changes to your version of the plugin which should tie you over till a fix is pushed to the official bower repository.

In bower_components/requirejs-plugins/src/font.js at line 37 change it from:

```
req([(document.location.protocol === 'https:'? 'https' : 'http') +'://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js'], function(){
```

to:

```
req([(document.location.protocol === 'https:'? 'https' : 'http') +'://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js'], function(WebFont){
```

That "WebFont" is the one that is being complained about.